# xml parsing takes extra spaces

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have been trying to write/parse xml file in python. The tags are very simple

```
<main>
   <data>
     abcdef
   </data>
</main>
```

I have written this xml using xml document writer from xml.dom.minidom.

How-ever when i try to parse this and try to fetch data-text value, i get 'abcdef' with spaces/carriage return/newline characters in beg and end.
Does parsing does not take of indenting spaces? 
Following is the parsing snippet (ref from net)

```
dom = parseString(data)
clipTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('clipdata')[0].toxml()
clipData=clipTag.replace('<clipdata>','').replace('</clipdata>','')
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: No, parsing doesn't strip whitespace. Because unlike HTML, XML does not ignore whitespace (at least strictly speaking).

Answer (score 2):

Just use `strip()` to take out the extra white space.  If you only want to take out the leading white space, do `lstrip()`, as in `clipData.lstrip()`.

Answer (score 2):

In XML, whitespace is significant.  If you don't want whitespace in the data element, write it like this:

```
<main>
   <data>abcdef</data>
</main>
```